# Different Forms of Hölder's Inequality in Lp spaces

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I've came across two formulations of Holder inequality which are quite not the same for me. How to show that they are equivalent?.

Let $f(x) \in L^p$ and $g(x) \in L^q$ then

**Formula 1:** $\int_X |f\, g| \,\mathrm dx \leq \lVert f \rVert_{L_p} \lVert g \rVert_{L_q}$

**Formula 2:** $|\int_X f\,g \,\mathrm dx| \leq \lVert f \rVert_{L_p} \lVert g \rVert_{L_q}$

where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please use Mathjax for equations, e.g. $f(x) \in L^p$ instead of `f(x) \in L^p`

Comment: `Which one is the most correct`

Either they are correct, or they aren't. You should ask your question differently

Comment: How to show that they are equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

The two expressions $\int |fg|$ and $|\int fg|$, in general, are **not equal**. I'm not sure of what you mean by $L^p$ and $L^q$, but if $f(x) = \sin(x)$, $g(x) = 1$, the integration on $[0, 2\pi[$ will either give $2 \int_0^\pi \sin(x) dx = 4$ (formula 1) or $|\int_0^{2\pi } \sin(x) dx| = 0$ (formula 2). You can see this easily graphically:

[image: from geogebra]

In orange you have $\int |fg|$ and in purple $|\int fg|$. You have either $2 - (-2) = 4$, or $1 - 1 = 0 \neq 4$.

---

That said, if formula 1 is right, then formula 2 also is, because $|\int fg| \le \int|fg|$ since in one case you sum with only positive contributions and in the other with possible negative ones.

Hence I'd say that **formula 1 is stronger than formula 2**, which (sort of) answers your initial question "which one is the most correct ?".

I hope it helped !

Comment: $L^p$ means $p$ integrable, $L^q$ similarly, you would know this if you understood measure theory? (see tag). And they should be equivalent, iirc?

Comment: The inequalities in their formulation for all functions would usually be called equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Often, you will see Hölder's inequality defined as $\|fg\|_{L^1}\leq \|f\|_{L^p}\|g\|_{L^q}$ for $f\in L^p$ and $g\in L^q$. This is essentially your Formula 1.

Since $|\int fg dx|\leq \int |fg| dx=\|fg\|_{L^1}$, Formula 2 is just a consequence of Hölder's inequality.

Comment: Well understood. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In which sense do you mean "Originally"? Is it according to what you were taught, or Historically?

Comment: Good point, I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Originally, Hölder's inequality was proved with positive functions (see the paper by L.J. Rogers "An Extension of a Certain Theorem in Inequalities", *Messenger of Mathematics*, New Series, XVII (10): 145–150 (1988)), for which the two formulations are the same. Notice that the two statements:
$$\label{1}\tag{1}
\forall (f,g)\in L^p\times L^q,\,\int |f\,g| \leq \|f\|_{L^p}\,\|g\|_{L^q}
$$
and
$$\label{2}\tag{2}
\forall (f,g)\in L^p\times L^q,\,\Big|\int f\,g\Big| \leq \|f\|_{L^p}\,\|g\|_{L^q},
$$
are indeed equivalent. Indeed, \eqref{2} follows from \eqref{1} just because $\big|\int fg\big| \leq \int|fg|$, while \eqref{1} follows from \eqref{2} by considering the functions $|f|$ and $|g|$. Indeed, by inequality \eqref{2} used with these functions
$$
\int |f\,g| = \Big|\int |f|\,|g|\Big| \leq \|\,|f|\,\|_{L^p}\,\|\,|g|\,\|_{L^q} = \|f\|_{L^p}\,\|g\|_{L^q}.
$$

---

**Remark:** These inequalities are also equivalent to
$$\label{3}\tag{3}
\forall (f,g)\in L^p\times L^q,\,\int f\,g \leq \|f\|_{L^p}\,\|g\|_{L^q}
$$
which is the one I would usually call the Hölder's inequality, and (by considering the functions $|f|^r$ and $|g|^r$) to the inequality
$$\label{4}\tag{4}
\forall (f,g)\in L^p\times L^q,\,\|f\,g\|_{L^r} \leq \|f\|_{L^p}\,\|g\|_{L^q} \quad\text{  if } \frac{1}{r} = \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q}
$$